# СПП с двумя придаточными

Tags: стилистика, спп, смысл, придаточное-предложение

Правильно ли составлено предложение?

> С недавних пор трактир забит посетителями, что на руку хозяину, кошель которого истосковался по монетам и который трудился ради этого две недели.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141520/discussion-on-question-by-----).

Comment: @shampar Но вы хотели, хотя никто не просил (значит, никому это не нужно).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, действительно, *кошель, истосковавшийся по монетам*, — это нестандартно.
Во избежание комической ситуации (кошель трудился две недели), отошлем "тару для дензнаков" в конец предложения.

*С недавних пор трактир забит посетителями, что на руку хозяину, который трудился ради этого две недели и у которого кошель истосковался по монетам.*

**Дополнение**
А предложения такого типа встречаются (заменим хозяина на человека):
*Скоро среди представителей тогдашней литературы, профессоров университета и философов революции должен был появиться этот **человек, который** думал на все их темы **и у которого**, кроме терминологии, не было с ними ничего общего* (Б. Пастернак. Доктор Живаго);
*Понятен молодому **человеку, который** ко мне пришел **и у которого** очень мало на меня времени* (В. Красногоров. О драме и театре).

Comment: Чего это нестандартно? Обычная метафора.

Comment: Ну замените на "хозяйка". Это исправит ситуацию? Если нет, то проблема в другом.

Comment: Тогда лучше так: С недавних пор трактир забит посетителями, что на руку хозяину, который трудился ради этого две недели и  кошель которого истосковался по монетам.

Comment: То, что у вас, встречается и звучит (не всегда идеально), никто не говорил, что нет. Разговор об исходной структуре.

Answer (score 3):

Как-то "кошель" не вписывается в тему, так как они с хозяином одного (мужского) рода.

Можно записать так:

***С недавних пор трактир забит посетителями, что на руку хозяину, истосковавшемуся по монетам, ради которых он и трудился  две эти недели.***

Но, может быть, будут предложены другие варианты, чтобы не расставаться с кошелем (все-таки интересный образ).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141522/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon----).